# Use this as parameter name in javascript function definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I saw a function definition like this in my learning vscode source code.

```js
export function once<T extends Function>(this: unknown, fn: T): T {
    const _this = this;
    let didCall = false;
    let result: unknown;

    return function () {
        if (didCall) {
            return result;
        }

        didCall = true;
        result = fn.apply(_this, arguments);

        return result;
    } as unknown as T;
}
```

But this argument is not passed when calling

```js
... ...
const self = trackDisposable({
    dispose: once(() => {
        markAsDisposed(self);
        fn();
    })
});
... ...
```

I want to determine if javascript will automatically pass this argument in this case

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `this` works in javascript - brush up on typescript definitions for functions ... *The JavaScript specification states that you cannot have a parameter called this, and so TypeScript uses that syntax space to let you declare the type for this in the function body.* as *[documented in documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)* - TL;DR - the `this` argument in the definition is not an actual argument to the function, it's purely for typescript purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrasing the [typescript documentation on this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)

> ### Declaring `this` in a Function
>
> TypeScript will infer what `this` should be in a function via code flow analysis
>
> But, there are a lot of cases where you need more control over what object `this` represents. Since the *JavaScript* specification states that you cannot have a parameter called `this`, *TypeScript* uses that syntax space to let you declare the type for `this` in the function body.
>
> This is common with "callback-style" APIs, where another object typically controls when your function is called. Note that you need to use function, and not an arrow function, to get this behaviour

In other words

```
export function once<T extends Function>(this: unknown, fn: T): T {
```

simply defines that `this` will be `unknown`, but the function takes a single argument, `fn : T`

Comment: Sorry, I used to read the full documentation of ts, but I forgot this detail. thank you

Comment: @Elliot - all good - I should remove the passive aggressiveness of that first sentence I guess :p